# Подключение данных из Postgres BD к OBIEE 12c

Tags: postgresql, обработка-ошибок

Хочу подключить к OBIEE 12c данные из Postgres DB. Есть ли официальная документации и возможность не использовать сторонние драйверы, как например от CData?
OBIEE развернут на Linux.
U.P.D. нужен ODBC драйвер, вопрос в том как его сейчас установить

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/12213/biee/BIEMG/GUID-914424A9-D431-43DB-A951-1C7996A3B61A.htm#datadirect_sql_srvr
```

- официальная документация по установке от Oracle

```
https://www.postgresql.org/ftp/odbc/versions/src/
```

- драйвер для скачки

```
https://odbc.postgresql.org/docs/unix-compilation.html
```

- компилятор для драйвера

Надеюсь кому-нибудь пригодится